# Force redraw on android opengl es 2 to go over 60 fps

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, opengl-es-2.0

I am currently working on some opengl es 2 benchmarking on android devices and, In order to go past 60 fps, I want the android equivalent of

```
glutPostRedisplay();
```

For the java code, I'm using a slightly modified version of the hello-gl2 sample, which uses my C++ code through android ndk, and I've been unable to figure out how and where I should, if it really is what i need, use

```
GLSurfaceView.requestRender();
```

I simple want to redraw, or step?, my application and my question is, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An old question that I'd forgotten about.

Anyway, each Android phone has a vsync limit that, to the extent of my knowledge, cannot be bypassed. Curiously enough, Kindle Fire seems to have this limit at ~56 fps while the Wildfire S has its limit at ~78 fps.

Answer (score 0):

GLSurfaceView use a thread loop to render, you can try

1. don't do any sleep in onDrawFrame to get full render fps
2. copy GLSurfaceView.java to your project and change the source what you want. 
   note: comment the line use "SystemProperties"